# Creating a template out of HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, html

lets say i have a parent-div. And in this div-container, i want to display 5 elements which have all the same structure. For example:

```
<div class="element">
 <p class="name">
 </p>
 <div class="logo">
 </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make an object or prototype out of it, so i dont have to generate every single HTML Element with their classes and src values with the appendChild-function and Dot-Notations in a for-loop?

Im thinking of something like:

```
for(let i = 0; i<=5;i++){
var element = new element(class,src1,src2 ...);
}
```

And the "element" is defined in a external class file or something familiar.

Im a beginner, so please show mercy :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to clone the node from the template's `content`. For example:

```js
const templateElement = document.querySelector("#someTemplate")
  .content
  .querySelector(".element");

// create an Array of nodes (so in memory)
const fiveNodes = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
  const nwNode = templateElement.cloneNode(true);
  //                                       ^ clone the whole tree
  nwNode.querySelector("p.name").textContent += ` #${i + 1}`;
  fiveNodes.push(nwNode);
}

// append the nodes to document.body
// this is faster than appending every element in the loop
fiveNodes.forEach(el => document.body.append(el));
```

```html
<template id="someTemplate">
<div class="element">
 <p class="name">I am node</p>
 <div class="logo"></div>
</div>
</template>
```